# My question was "put on hold as off-topic"

Tags: discussion

I posted my question [mac osx - Docker OS X - Is your docker daemon up and running? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/722228/docker-os-x-is-your-docker-daemon-up-and-running) on ServerFault, yet my question was put on hold due to:

> put on hold as off-topic by kce, EEAA♦ 37 mins ago
>
> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on-
>   and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by
>   reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this
>   specific reason:
>
> "Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information
>   technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user
>   computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about
>   development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack
>   Overflow." – kce, EEAA If this question can be reworded to fit the
>   rules in the help center, please edit your question.

My posted question actually has nothing to do with "development
system" and everything to do with "IT systems in a business
environment". I work as System Administrator in enterprise environment
and we're looking into using docker in our business.

I don't believe my question is off topic at all, question is not about
"home and end-user computing" and I am aware of Superuser & Stack
Overflow sites (I do post my question there that do not belong to
Server Fault).

Please review. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14):

I cast my vote to place your question on-hold for a combination of reasons:

1. Your question appears to be about using a one-click installer to
   generate a Docker environment on a end user's machine. The one-click
   installer also utilizes VirtualBox, a [piece of software of which
   the topicality](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/5529/in-what-circumstances-should-virtualbox-questions-be-on-topic) has been greatly debated on Meta.SF. One-click
   installers and VirtualBox are generally what the community considers
   developer tools. StackOverflow or SuperUser is generally a more
   appropriate place for those kinds of questions.
2. You just linked to an article of [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/mac/). This does not
   tell anyone how you followed them or where in the process you were
   when you encountered this problem. Linking to an article or
   instructions without context is generally indicative of a low
   quality question.
3. You copy/pasted a bunch of CLI output without context.
   Again, supplying a bunch of logs, shell output or configuration file
   contents without any context is indicative of a low quality
   question.
4. You did not supply any real information on what you actually
   trying to accomplish, the steps you followed to do so and where they
   failed. (See: [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault))
5. You are clearly familiar enough with the site and its
   requirements to have garnered a decent amount of rep (with the lack
   of voting 4k is significant). This combined with the other
   considerations clenched the deal for my close vote, I tend to be
   less lenient with long-term users.

Anyway - please don't take it personally. It is quite possible I voted to close your question in error. I think if you edit it to address some of these points you might find that it is better received.

Comment: I'm not talking it personally, in fact I do appreciate your feedback and hopefully with that I'll be able to learn how to ask better questions which at the end will benefit me as well as community.

Answer (score 9):

In this case, installing and configuring Docker on Linux on Virtualbox on OSX is no different than installing and configuring Visual Studio on Windows. It's a development tool, and this type of question is no more suited here than would be a question about how to properly configure syntax highlighting in an IDE.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, according to https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker docker is for both developers _AND_ sysadmins, but then again this is probably not a place to have this conversation here, but regardless I do respect your opinion.

Comment: I fully understand what docker is. In fact I use it every day. Your question, though was about configuring a **development environment**. Docker on Linux on Virtualbox on OSX is **not** a production environment. It's a developer's system.

Comment: This is _NOT_ development environment, We're using Macs in _PRODUCTION_ and with Macs that's how docker works (via VirtualBox).

Comment: @alexus You're seriously running Docker on VirtualBox on a Mac...in production?! You have bigger problems to solve.

Comment: @MichaelHampton no, not yet, just considering it. I guess it's all depends on requirements for project...

Answer (score 8):

I had nothing to do with closing this question, but I would have been comfortable closing it as "Off Topic / No Clear Problem Statement".  However, the "not sysadmin" threshold really isn't met, either, because Docker-on-Mac-OS-X is overwhelmingly a "development tool".

Your question doesn't exactly scream "I'm a professional", either.  The error message seems pretty clear about what's going wrong, and you don't acknowledge that you've read it and even attempted to understand what it means.

Comment: You're 100% correct, I should've included more information. Thank you for your feedback.