# But What About Otto? Can we hate that yet?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-topics

Since SF likes to [play whack-a-mole with products that it doesn't like](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8378/what-should-we-do-with-questions-about-vagrant/), let's get the decision to hate Otto out of the way early.

[Otto](https://hashicorp.com/blog/otto.html), if you hadn't heard, is the successor to Vagrant.

I think this is a natural candidate for excluding because it deals with Tech Professionals doing their jobs, even if that means Developers deploying code and having environments consistent with production, and that would help address the "Works on my machine" problem...

Answer (score 11):

First, what's with the snark?

If you hadn't noticed, the three most upvoted answers on that question ([1](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8379/20815), [2](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8381/20815), [3](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/8382/20815)) proposed that yes, we would accept questions about vagrant, provided that it is otherwise on-topic.

The same will hold true for questions about Otto.

Comment: Possibly. I'm still reserving judgment on it; anything that _advertises_ that it lets developers deploy to production worries me.

Comment: Understood. There are a ton of utilities that would let developers deploy to production, and I don't think that we should throw the baby out with the bathwater. With both Otto and Vagrant, I think a more nuanced approach is warranted. I'll gladly close questions for both if they're blatantly off-topic.